# How can I get a list of unique endpoints using GetEndPoints()

Tags: c#, .net, redis, stackexchange.redis

I need to get a list of all masters I'm currently connected to.  This should be pretty easy:

```
private IEnumerable<IServer> Masters => connection
        .GetEndPoints()
        .Select(e => connection.GetServer(e))
        .Where(s => !s.IsSlave);
```

This works locally, but in production where we connect against a cluster, it returns duplicate masters and screws up my code.  The reason for this is our connection string is "RedisServer1:7000,RedisServer2:7000", so we get one EndPoint which is a DnsEndPoint with RedisServer1, and one EndPoint which is an IPEndPoint which is 10.0.0.15 (or some IP) since it's using everything in the cluster.  Those two endpoints point to literally the same box.  So, I thought I could do this:

```
private IEnumerable<IServer> Masters => connection
        .GetEndPoints()
        .Where(e => e is IPEndPoint)
        .Select(e => connection.GetServer(e))
        .Where(s => !s.IsSlave);
```

This fixes production, so I no longer have dupes.  However, then our functional tests break because they're using a non-cluster, single Redis instance which is just a DnsEndpoint of "localhost".

I could probably use some sort of "group by" and filter out dupes, but the DnsEndpoints have host names and the IPEndPoints have IP addresses, so there's not *really* a way to tell if two endpoints are the same.  I was looking for some sort of globally unique "Redis instance ID" or something, but there doesn't appear to be such a thing.  Maybe I can somehow tell if I'm connected to a cluster and change my logic based on that?

What's the best way to fix this?

**Update:** To clarify what I mean, if I have a 6-node cluster running on Localhost, `GetEndPoints()` will return 7 things:

[image]

(Array elements 0 and 4 are the same thing)

Comment: Maybe just resolve `DnsEndPoint`s to ip addresses via `Dns.GetHostEntry`, so that you only have a list of IPs? Then you can filter out duplicates.

Comment: @Evk - Yea, I think that would be doable!  It would add a bit of network overhead, but this is a function that only runs when the site starts up..

Comment: Maybe it won't give any overhead even, since redis api should have already done the same to resolve hosts to ips, so all those hosts are probably in local dns cache anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a perfect answer, but here's what I came up with:

```
private IEnumerable<EndPoint> Endpoints
{
    get
    {
        EndPoint[] endpoints = connection.GetEndPoints();
        IServer firstServer = connection.GetServer(endpoints.FirstOrDefault());

        return firstServer?.ServerType == ServerType.Cluster ? firstServer.ClusterConfiguration.Nodes.Select(n => n.EndPoint) : endpoints;
    }
}

private IEnumerable<IServer> Masters => Endpoints
        .Select(e => connection.GetServer(e))
        .Where(s => !s.IsSlave);
```

Basically, I look at the server at the first endpoint.  If that server is part of a cluster, I return all the nodes in the cluster.  Otherwise, I just return all the endpoints.

This solution has the theoretical flaw if you had endpoints that pointed to multiple clusters, or pointed to a mix of clusters and standalone instances.  I really hope no one is doing that though.

It could also probably use a bit more null checking if you had zero endpoints.